# Images not appearing on Emulator or Phone

Tags: android, jquery

I'm testing out an application I've created but I've run into 1 issue. Some of the images that should load up and render into the app, don't show up at all. As far as I can see there is nothing I am doing different for either the images that show up or the images that won't. The application works in both DreamWeaver and in Google Chrome with no issues. I'm storing the images in a image folder inside of the www folder. All image names are named correctly.

The way I am calling these images is like this

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/Font/image1.png" id="chooseImg" /></td>
</tr>
```

There is obviously something I am doing wrong, I just can't see what it is, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are there any 404 errors showing up on the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. Is there anything specific I should be looking for in LogCat?

Comment: Looking through the LogCat. There are AndroidProtocolHandler Errors that are set to the missing images. Is there a solution for that? It shows up as "Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/images/imageFolder/image1.png"

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the path. Do you have the folder structure that you are referring to?

Comment: @Raghu unless DW and Google Chrome handle paths differently to emulators and phones. There is no issue with the path. They show up perfectly fine using the first 2.

Comment: But looking at the log, it appears to be path issue. Check this one where someone else had the similar issue. https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/174521/alloy-widget-problem

Comment: Screenshot of folder structure and errors here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vMLgB.png

Comment: One thing I noticed is the folder names start with upper case where as they are referred to by lower case.

Comment: *facepalm*. I am a complete moron. I double and triple checked the image names without checking the folder names. Well I'm gonna put this down to trying to get fix this at 5 am instead of getting sleep and going at it when I've slept :) Thanks for the help mate. It's always the small things I miss

Comment: no worries John. Happens even to the best of the people. Let me know if you want me to post this as an answer that you can accept so others can benefit if they run into the same issue.